# Swapping Axes of single variable ContourPlot

Tags: graphics

I have a `ContourPlot` dependent on one parameter, where the second parameter is dependent on the first:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x + y], {y, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 3y}]
```

[image]

I would like to have the dependent "x" axis on the vertical direction and the independent "y" axis on the horizontal. That is, I would like to swap the two axis.

In a `ContourPlot` of two variables this can be easily achieved by swapping the order of appearance of the limits. But with one limit dependent on the other, the independent limit must always appear first in the options.

How do I swap my axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html):

```
 ContourPlot[ConditionalExpression[Cos[x + y], x <= 3 y],  {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

#### [`ReflectionTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReflectionTransform.html):

```
cp = ContourPlot[Cos[x + y] , {y, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 3 y}];

Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]] &, cp, {1}], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

> same picture

Comment: The Conditional Expression only really works for this MWE. The limits I am considering are more complicated (they vary as a function of the independent parameter) so they cannot be written down as a single algebraic condition.

Comment: @OldTomMorris, afaik `ConditionalExpression` should work; can you post an example of where `ContourPlot[foo[x,y],{y, y_min,y_max}, {x, f(y)_min, g(y)_max}]` works but `ContourPlot[ConditionalExpression[foo[x,y], f{y}_min>=x<=g(y)_max], {x, x_min, x_max},{y, y_min,y_max}]` doesn't?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. `ConditionalExpression ` does indeed work, I have just attempted it. I have selected your answer as the answer, thanks!

Comment: @OldTomMorris, thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 1):

Considering most general solution for any type of plot or graphics, first thing that comes to mind is swapping the coordinate system "from inside" by swapping x-y coordinates of underlying `Graphics` object (examine it by applying `InputForm` to your final plot). Then use `PlotRange->Automatic` and arbitrary `FrameLabel` to set names of the axis as you wish.

```
Show[
    ContourPlot[Cos[x+y],{y,0,2},{x,0,3y}]
        /.GraphicsComplex[a_List,b___]:>
        GraphicsComplex[Reverse/@a,b],
PlotRange->Automatic,FrameLabel->{"horizontal","vertical"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure wether the axes labeling of your plot is ok?

But I can provide a swapped ContourPlot using RegionFunction:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x + y], {y, 0, 6}, {x, 0, 2}  ,RegionFunction ->Function[{x, y}, x <= 3 y]]
```

[image]

Comment: Fixed the labelling, apologies. The idea nonetheless is not to plot `Cos[x+y]` but some more complicated function with limits `{y, y_min,y_max}, {x, f(y)_min, g(y)_max}` .

Comment: That could all be accomplished using RegionPlot or  ConditionalExpression(answer kglr)!

Comment: Indeed, `ConditionalExpression` does the job. Thanks!